# Firebase storage Image ulpoad and rules set allow read but get link 403 Forbidden openresty

Tags: node.js, firebase

Hello I upload some image for my Firebase storage. I modify the rules on storage. But I got page with it's link: 403 Forbidden openresty.
(Otherwise I made Full Stack React & Firebase Tutorial - Build a social media app and still 2:08:00 work fine but I now stucked) Please answer somebody know the solution Thank you

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase support answer my question. There wasn't problem with the rules but the url was mispelled that point that images in database. So only one wrong letter in URL...